# Joomla 3 with Bootstrap 3 collapse menu and module not assigned

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

Here is an example Joomla 3 site http://kaikkikotona.fi/joomlatest/ with Bootstrap. The problem is when using the site with mobile device. Luckily the problem arises in PC screen when it is narrowed to a mobile size.

The third page has no Login Form. I have defined that the module is not shown on that page. Bootstrap collapse menu is not working in this page. I found the reason but I don't know how to fix it.

Collapse menu needs jQuery. It is loaded via Joomla code

```
< jdoc:include type="head" />
```

and that will produce in the head element

```
<script src="/joomlatest/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).on('load',  function() {
        new JCaption('img.caption');
    });
    window.setInterval(function() {
        var r;
        try {
            r = window.XMLHttpRequest?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        }
        catch(e){}
        if(r){
           r.open("GET","./",true);
           r.send(null)
        }
    },840000);
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.hasTooltip').tooltip({"html": true,"container": "body"});
    });
</script>
```

BUT in the third page that the module is not show bootstrap.min.js is not loaded and the script is only window onload function.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself.

The solution is to write few lines of code in the file index.php

```
<jdoc:include type="head" />   
<?php   
// Add Bootstrap Frameworks   
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');   
?>
```

It seemed that Bootstrap files are loaded automatically but in fact you have to load them with own code.